# What do empty curly brackets/braces mean in Java?

Tags: java

Here is the whole source code:

http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html

Here is the code I want to highlight:

```
Provider(){}
```

What does this line means? Thanks.

Comment: +1 - Great question! It's pretty basic of course, but it is thought-provoking and does highlight how the access level modifiers can be used to limit access and clarify the purpose of a class. I feel like many people overlook these things and don't see how they can communicate something like "This class is only used in this package and nowhere else".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that there's nothing to execute in this Constructor. Usually Java provides this by default so writing down Provider(){} is not necessary.

The main difference between this one and the one that is provided by the compiler by default is that the access is restricted since it's not public.

Comment: This is not actually the same as the constructor java creates. I believe the automatically created constructor has public visibilty. This one has default visibilty.

Comment: @javaCity - Edited your answer to make it more correct. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

It is a constructor with default accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

The no-arg constructor is simply being defined instead of being undeclared. However, since the access level modifier "public" was left out, this means the no-arg constructor is defined using the default package.

This means that any classes outside the package will not be able to instantiate it. Only classes within the package can instantiate the Provider class.

Answer (score 0):

It is [default constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor) which does nothing.

An object of this class can be created withing the package.